# Why Coroutine in Non-MonoBehaviour Script is not Working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to call coroutine in a non-monobehavior script but this approach is not working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attacking : BaseState
{
    private MovementSM _sm;
    public float movementSpeed;
    public MonoBehaviour mono;        //here i calling monobehaviour
    public bool attackBool;

    public Attacking(MovementSM stateMachine) : base("Attacking", stateMachine)
    {
        _sm = stateMachine;
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
        base.Enter();
        _sm.animator.SetTrigger("attack");
       
    }

    public override void UpdateLogic()
    {
        base.UpdateLogic();
        mono.StartCoroutine(DelayFunction());   //calling couroutine

    }

     IEnumerator DelayFunction()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        Debug.Log("Test!");
    } 
}
```

i tried to acces the monobehaviour using parser method. but it is not clear and didnt work. how to solve this problem. what is wrong in this code.

I tried the other method shown in stackoverflow but not working.

Comment: Don't see why it shouldn't work this way ... Do you ever assign a reference to `mono` though ..? `here i calling monobehaviour`  .. no there you only declare a field .. you still need to assign a reference to it otherwise it is simply `null` ...

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance and MonoBehaviour aren't friends. In C# you can't inherit from two base classes. There are good reasons for that, but we have to deal with the inconvenience from time to time.

Problem with your script is that the `mono` variable is null and therefore you will get an error on the `StartCoroutine` line. Typically you would resolve that by constructing the missing class like this:

```csharp
public MonoBehaviour mono = new MonoBehaviour();
```

Only problem with that, there is no constructor for MonoBehaviour (at least not one that is accessible). Sadly I don't have a document to quote, so take it with a grain of salt.

There is a workaround, that basically involves running the Coroutine thru your MonoBehaviour derived base class. I'm assuming that your `BaseState` is derived from MonoBehaviour.

```csharp
public override void UpdateLogic()
{
  base.UpdateLogic();
  base.StartCoroutine(DelayFunction());
}
```